# How do I prevent the installation to fail during the step of taking a picture?

Tags: installation, webcam

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04, but when during the installation I face some difficulty regarding the step in which Ubuntu tries to take a picture using the webcam.

There is a window, when Ubuntu tries to take a picture and at that point the installation is interrupted. Should I look for a proper webcam driver? Or, should I find a way to disable the camera so that I prevent this step?

I'm using old **Asus A8JN** with a Core Duo T2300E, 2.5 GB memory and a 160 GB HDD.

I think that camera is "YaHsin Chicony" but i'm not sure.

```
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0ac8:0321 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp.
Vimicro generic vc0321 Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:5307 Hewlett-Packard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:1712 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. BT-183 Bluetooth 2.0+EDR adapter
```

and there is a line from `usb-devices | grep Driver`:

```
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=vc032x
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This sounds like a bug, but of course there's a way to work around and disable this. We'll need more hardware information for that. Can you run from a live CD, "Try Ubuntu" and provide the output of `lsusb` run from a terminal? Also, the output of `usb-devices | grep Driver` should show one of the webcam drivers (e.g. `uvcvideo`). Do this by *editing* your question. I can provide an answer on how to disable this during installation then.

Comment: helped command: sudo rmmod gspca_vc032x

here is little more about the problem
[link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/990749)

Answer (score 1):

Below are steps to disable the kernel module (driver) for your webcam (`gspca_vc032x`), temporarily, using the initial boot menu of the Ubuntu Live image. It basically is just using the kernel boot parameter `modprobe.blacklist=gspca_vc032x` to do so.

1. In the initial boot menu when booting the live image, press any key to enable the menu.
2. Select your language; I chose English here.
3. *Highlight* the option you want to continue using later (e.g. *Try Ubuntu without installing*). Don't start yet!
4. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> (Other Options)
5. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to escape from this menu and start a custom editor of the kernel boot parameter line.
6. The cursor should be at the end of the line now ending with `--`. Remove the two dashes.
7. Type `modprobe.blacklist=gspca_vc032x`
8. Press <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to boot.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can disable the kernel module *after* you booted as well.

1. Boot Ubuntu (live image) the regular way.
2. Before starting the installation, open a terminal.

   - Use the regular Terminal application <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, *or*,
   - A virtual terminal, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Log in using username `ubuntu` and no password.
3. Unload the kernel module to effectively disable the camera:

   ```
   sudo rmmod gspca_vc032x
   ```
4. Close the terminal application, or, if you used the virtual terminal, go back to the graphical screen using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
5. Continue as usual, starting the installation.